# Shipping method does not show until weight minimum reached

Tags: shipping, magento-2.1.7, fedex

I deal with products which have very little weight. Recently I noticed Fedex shipping methods are not showing up until my cart fills up to a certain point. For example, no shipping methods appear until *seven or more* `0.0008lb` items are added or when *four or more* `0.0014lb` items are added. So it seems that shipping methods are not showing up until I've added a minimum of at least `.0056lb` of weight to my cart.

[image]

This problem did not occur until recently, is anyone aware of a change in Fedex's API? Is there something else I can do to get around this problem?
 To my knowledge none of our settings have changed, hence why I suspect a change to Fedex's API. Any other insight or advice would be helpful right now we can't sell to a large portion of our customers. Has anyone or is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: To which version of Magento do you refer to?

Comment: 2.1.7, also added tags